# If condition in java

Tags: java, if-statement

`If` logic given below works well in C language but it doesn't work in java....Why..??
 It gives an error in java while compiling.

```
class test
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int i;
    if(i=4)
    System.out.println("hello");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C/C++ any non-zero value is considered as true, zero considered false. That is, int and bool are interchangeable. So `if (i = 4)` is true in C/C++. As `i` is getting the value 4 and this is equivalent to `if (4)`. But in Java boolean is different from int and you can not use int where boolean is required. Note then, `i == 4` is boolean but `i = 4` is int. The last one assignment, not compare.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the comparison operator (`==`) instead of the assignment operator (`=`) in your if statement.

In C, the result of a valid assignment operator [is the value that is assigned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29#Value_of_an_assignment). If your example was in C, the resultant code would be equivalent to `if(4)`, which evaluates to a true statement, and the code is always executed without any complaints by the compiler. Java checks for a few cases where you probably mean something else, such as this one.

Comment: In C the result of an assignment is the assigned value.

Comment: Yeah. I was just looking up to confirm. I knew it was either true or the assigned value, just not sure which. I edited to reflect this.

Comment: I've got the the theory that the if-condition needs a return value of type 'boolean', but in Java a (successful) declaration of a variable has no return value. So why an error orcurred.

Comment: Just as a note: In both C and Java the result of an assignment is the assigned value. The "problem" is that java doesn't allow the implicit conversion from integer to bool. Considering the bugs I had to debug in C over the years because of such a silly mistake I'm quite happy with that.

Comment: @qbert220 and Thomas Owens, it is the assigned value (value of the RHS) **after any (explicit or implicit) casts** necessary to convert it to the type of the LHS.  The latter is really only important in languages like C++ where implicit casts can be much more semantically significant than in Java or C, but Java has a weird quirk around compound assignment operators (`+=`) where lossy casts do not warn.  Consider `myInt = myByte += 256` in Java where `myInt` and `myByte` are initially zero;  `myInt` ends up `0` without any warning.

Answer (score 4):

I would not agree that it works well in C. Its confusing, even if it does compile.

This will also print "hello" in C

```
int i = 0;
if (i == 4) // i == 4 is not true
  cout << "hi";

if (i = 4) // i = 4 which is treated as true
  cout << "hello";
```

Which is why it is not allowed in Java.  You have to write

```
int i = 0;
if (i == 4) // false
  System.out.println("hello");
```

The closest you can get to this is problem is using the boolean type.

```
boolean b = false;
if (b = true)
  System.out.println("hello");
```

This compiles, but is almost certainly a bug.

One place assignment is commonly used is in reading lines of text

```
BufferedrReader br = 
String line;
// assigns and checks the value of readLine()
while((line = readLine()) != null) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the double equal sign `==`

```
class test
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int i = 4;
    if(i==4)
    System.out.println("hello");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It will compile in C because the condition of and if statement in C can be of type int. However, you assign 4 to `i` in your condition, and it will not do what you expect it to do in C either.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (i=4) {
}
```

will work in C but will not do what you expect. It will in fact check that i is non-0.

Java forces you to have an expression that evaluates to a boolean. Hence you need the == operator. The assignment operator in that case will evaluate to int.