# Why does my if condition not accept an integer in java?

Tags: java, if-statement

Currently I'm using:

```
 int a=10;
 if(a=20)
     printf("TRUE");
 else
     printf("false");
```

Which prints, in C, the value `TRUE`.

But in case of java:

```
int a=10;
if(a=20)
    System.out.println("TRUE");
else
    System.out.println("FALSE");
```

I'll get a compile time error about an incompatible type.

Comment: Read - Equality, Relational, and Conditional Operators -http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [If condition in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663039/if-condition-in-java)

Comment: why in case c it is working...

Comment: @SandeepTiwari : see Aleks G's answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason for that is that in C there is no specific type `boolean` - instead any non-0 integer evaluates to a boolean "true".  Thus in your C code:

```
if(a=20)
```

`a` is assigned the value 20, which is non-0 - and the condition is evaluated as `true`

In java, there's a fundamental type `boolean` and the value of the conditional inside `if` must be of this type.

```
a=20
```

in Java assigns 20 to `a` and returns the final result of evaluation as `integer value 20`, however type `boolean` is expected - hence you're getting a compile-time error about the incompatible types.

If you want to do a comparison of `a` with 20, however, you need to use `==` operator both in C and Java:

```
if(a == 20)
```

This will compile in both C and Java and print FALSE in both languages.

Answer (score 6):

You need to replace `=` with `==`.

`=` is an assignment operator

```
int a=10;
if(a==20){
System.out.println("TRUE");}
else{
System.out.println("FALSE");}
```

This should work fine.

Edit:

In C, the returned integer value of the assignment (in this case 20) is a positive int, which evaluates to true.
In java, a boolean is expected.

(See the more thorough answer provided by Aleks G)

Comment: It seems to me that you're missing the point of the question: he's not asking how to do comparison, but rather why the same code works in C and not in Java.  Yes, single vs double `=` sign has something to do with it, but it doesn't answer his question.  At the same time, maybe hes question is not well formulated and this really is what he's after.

Comment: hi sir I know that perhaps I can't write proper question or you not properly get my question please try to understant and compare with c code

Answer (score 2):

A single `=` is an *assignment.* If you want to test for equality, you use the *double* `==` in both C and Java.

It should be evident that you're doing the wrong thing, even in the C version, since you set `a` to 10 and then, on "comparing" it to 20, you get a true value. I'm not aware of *any* mathematical systems where 10 and 20 are considered equal :-)

What happens in your C case is that the assignment actually "returns" a value as well.

The statement:

```
if (a = 20) ...
```

is equivalent to:

```
a = 20;
if (a) ...
```

so it first sets `a` to 20, then uses that as the `if` condition. Since 0 is false and anything else is true, the body of the `if` is executed.

A good compiler (like `gcc`) will actually warn you of what you're doing so that you don't get caught out by these little things. Some people also use the trick of putting constants first:

```
if (20 == a) ...
```

so that, if you mistakenly use assignment, it's a syntax error. But I find that sort of code ugly, especially since I mostly use those good compilers mentioned above :-)

The reason you get an error in Java is because it's much more strict on what you can do with assignments. By that, I mean there is no automatic conversion from `int` to `boolean` as with C. So this code refuses to compile, producing an error:

```
class Test {
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 10;
        if (a = 20)
            System.out.println ("true");
    }
}
```

But you can *still* get burnt with something like this:

```
class Test {
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        boolean a = false;
        if (a = true)
            System.out.println ("true");
    }
}
```

Because that assignment is of a boolean value inside the `if`, it doesn't cause a compilation error due to the wrong type. However, since it prints `true`, it's still not what you wanted.

Bottom line, go back an re-read that first paragraph. `=` is assignment, `==` is equality checking.

Comment: Please why it didn't work in java case only focuse on this question ...?

Comment: @Sandeep, start reading from the paragraph "The reason you get an error in Java ..." - that should hopefully explain it for you.

Comment: thanks for your valueable answer sir......I ahve no any problem regarding = & == my question  is only that why it work in c and not in java...which have been solved right now..

Comment: @Michael, fat finger syndrome, it should have been `10` :-)

Comment: I figured as much, but didn't want to edit since I wasn't certain. :) Those things happen.

Answer (score 0):

for comparison you should use ==

`if(a==20)` instead of `a=20`, which is assignment

Answer (score 0):

Use the `==` to test the condition instead of `=`. That way, you are assigning `20` `to` a and not testing for a condition.

Answer (score 0):

if (a==20) ... or

System.out.println(a==20);

Answer (score 0):

value of `a=20` is 20. You should use `==` operator.